# Can't access "settings"

Tags: error-message, settings

I can access "settings" in the control panel.
Getting these errors:

Please help.

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined property: DOMElement::$tagName in /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(76): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/I/ingvild...', 258)
#1 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php(258): craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/I/ingvild...', 258, Array)
#2 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php(190): enshrined\svgSanitize\Sanitizer->startClean(Object(DOMNodeList))
#3 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Extension.php(996): enshrined\svgSanitize\Sanitizer->sanitize('<?xml version="...')
#4 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/df/df31c94529800ceb7cf955ac5b5898c4e29f5ce98a4036e2217e6a61ea2f3f9c.php(102): craft\web\twig\Extension->svgFunction('<?xml version="...', true, true)
#5 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_19447abc33fb7a0c8a6ea8e2896fa28f2fdfaa15a1635e7b6596d2d49a561a4a->block_content(Array, Array)
#6 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/36/36b7901590569872e594edf5fc206bc4a57e68c8698825c136c9364e4f05802a.php(727): Twig\Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#7 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_ebe869e9a651c411e685951475d955b121115babe7839dd2e4a9619bcb142633->block_main(Array, Array)
#8 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/36/36b7901590569872e594edf5fc206bc4a57e68c8698825c136c9364e4f05802a.php(576): Twig\Template->displayBlock('main', Array, Array)
#9 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_ebe869e9a651c411e685951475d955b121115babe7839dd2e4a9619bcb142633->block_body(Array, Array)
#10 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/11/111893239f215e3af27c5d8e8cf5e1776066036d9281c6469233b871fbdb4b01.php(75): Twig\Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#11 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_f051dde34a9248c9b67a2ac19b8fb693fe3d7b07822ea8691632a639c8cd279d->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#12 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#13 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/a3/a3098a83627ef0bb62694bfcaed4612c70665794a9d64fe7a7693cfea3c85fe8.php(56): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#14 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_32447755020e8cbca725f1701ba29c5e1624dc55b1ce88cfc5cafe1c1be67592->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#15 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#16 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/36/36b7901590569872e594edf5fc206bc4a57e68c8698825c136c9364e4f05802a.php(118): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#17 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_ebe869e9a651c411e685951475d955b121115babe7839dd2e4a9619bcb142633->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#18 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#19 /home/I/ingvildholmno/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/df/df31c94529800ceb7cf955ac5b5898c4e29f5ce98a4036e2217e6a61ea2f3f9c.php(49): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#20 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_19447abc33fb7a0c8a6ea8e2896fa28f2fdfaa15a1635e7b6596d2d49a561a4a->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#21 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#22 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(392): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#23 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
#24 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
#25 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(344): Twig\Environment->render('settings', Array)
#26 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(393): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('settings', Array)
#27 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(243): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('settings', Array)
#28 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(101): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('settings', Array)
#29 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('settings', Array)
#30 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#32 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(187): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#33 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#34 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(299): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#35 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#36 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(284): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#37 /home/I/ingvildholmno/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#38 /home/I/ingvildholmno/www/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#39 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web server doesn't have the PHP DOM extension installed and I'm guessing you're doing something in a template that requires it. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

If you install that, the error should go away.